# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES with JDK 1.7

Tags: java-7, apk, jarsigner

I have **manually signed APK using JDK 7**. While installing I got the "`INSTALL PARSE FAILED NO CERTIFICATES`" error. I have referred some sites and got an idea to use `different signing algorithm for JDK 7`.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystorefile]
[originalapk] alias_name
```

Still getting the same error. Coudl you please guide me what i have missed